# HTML5 Video hide timeline control , basically disable the ability to drag the timeline in IE and also default it to fullscreen

Tags: css, webkit, html5-video

I got this working in chrome using webkit-media controls but not able to get it working in IE

I have used the following code

```
    <style>
    video#videoplayer {  position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100; background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;  z-index: 100000        }
    video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button,video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-container ,video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
display: none;
}
</style>

   <video  id="videoplayer" controls="controls" autoplay  onclick="this.paused?this.play():this.pause();">
                        <source src="samplevideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
                        <source src="samplevideo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                        <source src="samplevideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                        <object classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" >
                            <param name="URL" value="samplevideo.mp4" />
                             <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
                             <param name ="" value="true" />
                            <param name="windowlessVideo" value="true" />
                            <param name="AutoSize" value="TRUE" />
                            <embed src="samplevideo.mp4" type="application/x-mplayer2" windowlessvideo="TRUE" ></embed>
                        </object>
                    </video>
```

I want to hide the video timeline also default the video to full screen mode in IE

Comment: Why would anyone want something to default to fullscreen mode?

Comment: @N.J.Dawson - unfortunately that is the requirement

Comment: I removed the controls attribute in the video tag